# Split rows and assign a specific value to each group

Tags: postgresql

I have a scenario where i need to split rows in a table and assign certain values to a column for each group.
 The table name is customers(contains around 300K rows) and i need to split the customers in this table into 9 groups and update each group with a specific value in the "Value" column.

Anyone have any idea on how to do this using PostgreSQL?

This is the table structure(only a part)

```
Create table customers
(Customer_id  integer,
Customer_email TEXT,
updated_time TIME STAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
Value TEXT
)

Insert into customers Values(1,'sss@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(2,'abc@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(3,'retro@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(4,'als@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(5,'s123@neferce.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(6,'tt@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(7,'a123@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(8,'sabc@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(9,'67890@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(10,'qwert@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(11,'dfg@gmail.com',now(),'')
Insert into customers Values(12,'fvc@gmail.com',now(),'')
```

The above is the sample table structure and values and now i want the customers in this table to be split into 4 groups(in real i have to split into more groups say like 9 or 10) and update the Value column with a specific text for the split groups.

```
so the first 4 rows will be assigned with a value 'dos-1-1'
second set of 4 rows with a value 'dos-2-2'
Third set of 4 rows with a value 'dos-3-3'
Fourth set of 4 rows with a value 'dos-4-4'
```

Below is the desired result,

```
ID        Email              Date         Value
1   "sss@gmail.com"     "2019-06-14"    "dos-1-1"
2   "abc@gmail.com"     "2019-06-14"    "dos-1-1"
3   "retro@gmail.com"   "2019-06-14"    "dos-1-1"
4   "als@gmail.com"     "2019-06-14"    "dos-2-2"
5   "s123@neferce.com"  "2019-06-14"    "dos-2-2"
6   "tt@gmail.com"      "2019-06-14"    "dos-2-2"
7   "a123@gmail.com"    "2019-06-14"    "dos-3-3"
8   "sabc@gmail.com"    "2019-06-14"    "dos-3-3"
9   "67890@gmail.com"   "2019-06-14"    "dos-3-3"
10  "qwert@gmail.com"   "2019-06-14"    "dos-4-4"
11  "dfg@gmail.com"     "2019-06-14"    "dos-4-4"
12  "fvc@gmail.com"     "2019-06-14"    "dos-4-4"
```

Above is the situation and in real the table consists of around 300k rows and need to split it into 9 groups and update each group with a  specific text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Customer_id, NTILE(4) OVER ()::TEXT "Value" FROM customers )
UPDATE customers
SET "Value" = 'dos-' ||  cte."Value" || '-' ||  cte."Value"
FROM cte
WHERE customers.Customer_id = cte.Customer_id;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nXGx4kREAcPV8EL5Yyr9nP/0)

PS. It's recommended to use some ORDER BY in OVER clause (for example by `Customer_id`) - without it the result is not deterministic...